# How redirect subdomain to folder

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i want to redirect subdomain to folder, here on SO are some examples so i tried them but nothing works, now i got this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} http://test.web8.eu [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http://web8.eu/sub/test/$1" [L,P]
```

can anyone help me with this?

Can i rewrite subdomain to folder instead redirecting??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} test\.web8\.eu [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://web8.eu/sub{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]
```

Try adding this to the `.htaccess` file in your web document root folder (often `public_html` or `htdocs`): 
This assumes that mod_rewrite is **both** installed **and** activated for htaccess files. 
If you are not sure, to check if mod_rewrite is installed, look at the list of installed modules in the output of `phpinfo();`
By default, mod_rewrite is not enabled for htaccess files. If you are managing your own server, open `httpd.conf`
and make sure that the webroot directory block contains one of these lines: `AllowOverride FileInfo` or `AllowOverride All`

Comment: server still responds with Forbiden, maybe i should do something with server settings

Comment: Try adding `Options -Multiviews` before the three lines above.

Comment: Check the installation checklist I added.

Comment: I just deleted htaccess content and copy/paste your solution, now it works, thank you very much.
I got one more question - is it possible to rewrite it and not redirect - the adress will be test.web8.eu but contetn will be in subfolder?